# How to get fields from a table where its primary key is used in another table in 2 possible fields

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have 2 sql tables

```
    CREATE TABLE users(userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, alias TEXT NOT NULL)
    CREATE TABLE friends(userID1 INTEGER, userID2 INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(userID1, userID2))
```

When 2 users want to be friends, I create a new relationship btw the 2 by inserting a row in the **friends** table. The order for the **userID** of the 2 friends in the row do not matter but it should be unique, whatever the order.

**Question 1:**
My second table do not currently reflect what I want. I mean I can do this and it's fine while I don't want it to be:

```
    INSERT INTO friends VALUES(1,2);
    INSERT INTO friends VALUES(2,1);
```

Is it possible to enforce this constraint in my sql table, or should I check with a query if there is not already a relationship in the reversed order.

**Question 2:**
What is the most optimal sql query to get the list of friends (**userID** and **alias**) if I have a **userID**, if I have for example:

```
    INSERT INTO users VALUES(1, 'A');
    INSERT INTO users VALUES(2, 'B');
    INSERT INTO users VALUES(3, 'C');
    INSERT INTO users VALUES(4, 'D');
    INSERT INTO friends VALUES(1, 2);
    INSERT INTO friends VALUES(2, 3);
    INSERT INTO friends VALUES(4, 1);
    INSERT INTO friends VALUES(2, 4);
```

I want:

```
For userID=1: (2, B) and (4, D)
For userID=2: (1, A), (3, C) and (4, D)
For userID=3: (2, B)
For userID=4: (1, A) and (2, B)
```

**Bonus question:** Can I improve the tables to better reflect what I want?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: very good question,well framed

Answer (score 0):

One question at a time.  Change your insert from this structure:

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
values
(value1, value2, etc)
```

to this structure

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
select distinct value1, value2, etc
from someSmallTable
where not exists
(subquery to check for existing rows)
```